# Why AngularJs scope-checkbox not synced with inner properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Solved**
Dont forget use angular $timeout without native setTimeout

I'm have some property im model, that I'm display as checkbox
And I'm have $scope.watch, that monitoring it changes, and after that - do somth as for it state

Buuut... in value I'm have old value when I'm ckecking it

Sample & instruction: https://jsfiddle.net/L1f37px4/12/
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="hangarApp" ng-controller="hangarController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showOnlyPremiums" id="showPremId">
  <label for="showPremId">ClickMe</label>
  <div>{{showOnlyPremiums}}</div>
  <textarea readonly="readonly">{{testVar}}</textarea>
<p>
step 1. not checked? yes, false<br>
step 2. click it! and?.. only higher value changed<br>
step 3. surprise! click anywhere on free place. lower value changed too<br>
step 4. clicks more not repeat this. but values are not syncs....<br><br>
w.t.f???
</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var hangarApp = angular.module('hangarApp', []);

  // CONTROLLER
  hangarApp.controller('hangarController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.showOnlyPremiums = false;
    $scope.testVar = $scope.showOnlyPremiums;
    $scope.$watchGroup(['showOnlyPremiums'], function() {
      // watcherByChanges();
      $scope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', {});
    });
    $scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function(event, data) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.testVar = $scope.showOnlyPremiums;
      });
    });

  });

})();
```

Using AngularJs 1.6

PS: Sorry for my English. It's not my language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper more fundamental problem. In addition it creates an unnecessary browser render cycle that can result in possible unpleasant flickering.

Instead of using a watcher and [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to react to changes instigated by user input:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showOnlyPremiums" 
       id="showPremId" ng-change="onBoxCheckChange(showOnlyPremiums)" />
```

```
$scope.onBoxCheckChange = function(value) {
    $scope.testVar = value;
};
```

The [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

---

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.onBoxCheckChange = function(value) {
        $scope.testVar = value;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showOnlyPremiums" 
           id="showPremId" ng-change="onBoxCheckChange(showOnlyPremiums)" 
    /> Show Only Premiums
    <br>
    testVar={{testVar}}
</body>
```

Comment: I'll trying this. Thanx fo adwice!